What is the best/fastes way in c++ to replace a certain line in a file?
I am working on a project, and my code works. The problem is that it takes too long for the program to finish its task. My guess is that the program is slow because of the code shown below. This code is used multiple times in the programm. Essentially, I am reading the entire given file into a vector, modifying the line, and then writing the entire vector back into the file. I know this approach is slow and can become a major problem when the file size is large, but I haven't found a better way to do it.
int File::file_line_replace_agent(const std::string& file_path, int line_number, const std::string& new_line) {

// Opening file
std::ifstream inputFile(file_path);
if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
    return -1;
}

std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string currentLine;

// Writing all line of the file into the vector
while (std::getline(inputFile, currentLine)) {
    lines.push_back(currentLine);
}
inputFile.close();

// Looking if the given line is in scope of the file
if (line_number < 1 || line_number > static_cast<int>(lines.size())) {
    return -1;
}

// copy the new line in to the vector
lines[line_number - 1] = new_line;

// Writing the vector into the file
std::ofstream outputFile(file_path);
if (!outputFile.is_open()) {
    return -1;
}

for (const auto& l : lines) {
    outputFile << l << std::endl;
}
outputFile.close();
return 0;

}

The only way to replace text in a file, or add lines in the middle of a file, is to rewrite the entire file from the point of the first modification.

As @user12002570 wrote, in the general case, the only way is to write the whole file. In specifica cases, you could implement some optimisations, e.g. if replaceing a file near the end of the file you could just replace the end, if reading the same file often, you could cache it, if you have the flexibiility, you could write in a different format, or write temporarily in a different format etc.

You have lots of possible options here. If you can replace the format, consider using a database (SQLite is a good drop-in option) which will permit rapid modification of entries. If you don't need to persist changes to disk until you're done, read the file to an in-memory structure at the start and then modify it there. Or, consider splitting the file up into smaller ones (maybe temporarily). However, you haven't explained what constraints you have, so all we can do is guess what might work for you.

Probably too broad to answer. You've stumbled on database programming here (I did a little database programming in my first job in C, but the details are hazy). Presumably there are lots of textbooks out there on the topic. (Perhaps a starting point would be to have a separate file with indexing data into the main text file.)

One possible optimization I can think of is that, you could write a new file (temporary file), within the std::getline() loop itself thereby avoiding a vector.
If your line number validation fails, you can delete the temporary file and then return.
If all gets succeeded, you could replace the original file with the temporary file.

Does the file change between each read/update/write action? Or can you just read once, then update and write as many times as you need?

BTW, even though this thread seems dead... no one has mentioned the obvious: Are you sure it is this code that is the bottleneck in your program? Have you actually done any profiling to test your guess about what is taking time?

You could try to read/write the while file into/from memory in a single operation, as a chunk of binary data. You'd have to navigate through this data on your own to find the place you want to modify, but this would be an in-memory operation and rather fast, compared to line-by-line I/O operations.
The following code assumes that lines of your file are separated by "\n" or (preferably) "\r\n". For other line endings, and for UCS2 encoding, you must change the code accordingly. You should also insert some error checking. It reads the whole file at once, then writes the replaced line, then writes the rest of the file at once: 1 read operation, 2 write operations.
int ReplaceLine(char const* filename, int lineNumber, char const* replacement)
{
    // read the file into memory
    auto size = std::filesystem::file_size(filename);
    std::fstream stm(filename, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    std::vector<char> buffer(size);
    stm.read(buffer.data(), size);

    // find the start of the lineNumber'th line
    size_t pos = 0;
    while (lineNumber > 0)
    {
        auto findPos = std::find(begin(buffer) + pos, end(buffer), '\n');
        if (findPos == end(buffer))
            return 1; // no such line
        pos = (findPos - begin(buffer)) + 1;
        --lineNumber;
    }

    // find the end of the lineNumber's line
    auto findPos = std::find(begin(buffer) + pos, end(buffer), '\n');
    size_t endPos = findPos == end(buffer) ? size : findPos - begin(buffer);
    if (endPos > 0 && buffer[endPos-1] == '\r')
        --endPos;

    auto old_line_length = endPos - pos;
    auto new_line_length = strlen(replacement);

    // the beginning of the file is not changed
    stm.seekg(pos, std::ios_base::beg);
    // write the new line
    stm.write(replacement, new_line_length);
    if (endPos == size)
        // new text appended to the end of file? add a newline
        stm.write("\r\n", 2);
    else
        // new text in the middle of file? write the rest of the file
        stm.write(buffer.data() + endPos, size - endPos);

    stm.close();
    // if the replacement is shorter that the original line, we must truncate the file
    if (new_line_length < old_line_length)
        std::filesystem::resize_file(filename, size + new_line_length - old_line_length);
    return 0;
}


I think it would be better if you show how exactly to do what you're recommending.

@user12002570 Good idea. I edited my solution accordingly.
